# Differential amplifier with ideal current source and resistive loads

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, differential-amplifier

In this circuit, I want to find how each node's voltage changes as Vin changes.

My approach is as follows:
The total current is 2·I. The current in R is fixed and equal to I which implies that Vo2 is always constant and equal to Vdd - I·R and its gate to source voltage is adjusted corresponding to I i.e Vx = constant = -Vgs.

Now, as Vin increases, Vgs1 increases. This becomes a contradiction as the current of M1 is constant. So, could anyone help me out with understanding this?

[image]

Comment: When Vin increases more current from the left side flows down the tail and less from the right side. And vice versa. But as you mentioned total tail current is constant - as more flows from the left, less flows from the right. The current through R varies accordingly. If the circuit is perfectly symmetric, and both sides ground, 1I will flow from each side. As you increase Vin, left side 1.5I and right side 0.5I. At the extreme, left side 2I and right side 0 (right MOSFET is off). You could try this in the Falstad simulator.

Comment: If you connect a current source to two resistors in parallel - how is the current distributed between both resistors?   Will this distribution change if one resistor changes its value? (rule of current division).

Comment: Where is the contradiction? Vo1 will drop to equal Vx but the current will still be 'I' and the current through the right device will still be 'I'. There will be no voltage changes at Vo2. Your circuit is over-constrained.

Comment: @KevinWhite How does Vo1 equal Vx? I didn't get that. Could u explain a little more?

Comment: @prashanth - If device 1 attempts to conduct more than I the voltage across it will drop to zero.  In reality it will have a finite output resistance and the voltage across it will settle to a new non-zero voltage as Vin increases. Vo2 will never change though. In real circuits there is usually a current mirror to make the current through device 2 equal to that in device 1 (You should put a reference designator on devices in a schematic). You will then have the input stage of an opamp.

Comment: @KevinWhite Right side MOSFET current, drain voltage and gate voltage are constant. This should imply that the source voltage must also be constant. Isn't it?

Comment: @prashanth - yes. The only voltage that varies is Vo1. With a very small increase in Vin, Vo1 will drop until it equals Vx. If Vin is not high enough Vo1 will rise to infinity or until current source I stops functioning. It is not a practical circuit.

Comment: @KevinWhite Got the idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simulation shows no "real" behavior.
When some theoretical "current sources" are used, one should check the circuit.

Here is what happens :

[image]

[image]